# How can I add custom search box on page?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm using custom WordPress template and I don't know how to add search box in a specific place. Of course my template contains search box, but it is in a weird place, so I would like to add custom one. I cannot do that by adding widget. I have to edit `index.php` to add search box.

When I add this:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/">
<div><input type="text" size="18" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars($s, 1); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" class="btn" />
</div>
</form>
```

Basically, it is working. It is searching properly, but the search box is bad looking.

That one works as well:

```
<form method="get" id="search_form" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>"/>
       <input type="text" class="text" name="s" value="SEARCH" >
       <input type="submit" class="submit" value=""  />
</form>
```

But again, it looks awfull. I have to have custom css too.

And another one:

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

Works good, but the same problem. It is just like in 2000.

I tried adding custom css, but the problem is that id does not not searching anything on my website. Instead going to `http://example.com/?s=WHAT-I-TYPED` it goes to `http://example.com/`

What can I do with that?

Comment: theme-> editor ->header.php put your custom codes @audiophonic or maybe you can find a plugin to do this

Comment: But the custom css is showing properly. The thing is that when i click search on every custum search box id doesnt searching at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the UGLYNESS problem: Just add the plugin 'simple custom css': https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/. Then write some CSS to make it pretty.

To solve the SEARCH problem replace `name="search"` with `name="s"` on your input field (source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/).

Comment: I added this as custom css: `http://pastebin.com/8zuapgvr` and this in index.php `http://pastebin.com/0VG1ykDx` but when i search it goes to `http://example.com/?search=test&Search=Search#` instead of `http://example.com/?s=test`. What should I do?

Comment: PS. You have a typo in your text. You should replace 'Type your search hear' with 'Enter your search keywords here', or 'Type here to search'.

Comment: Ohh thanks a lot! It is almost done. There is another small bug. When i try to search from `www.example.com` everything works properly. But when i try to search from `www.example.com/page/2` it goes to `www.example.com/page/2/?s=test` instead of `www.example.com/?s=test`. In result It does not find anything. Here is css and html: `http://www.cssdesk.com/rSJET`

Comment: That is another problem, not related to this one. Please add another question.

Comment: Link 1 in the answer is a download link and link 2 is a reference/documentation link. Please check again.